# Not able to cover wrapper class in test class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, wrapper-class

I am trying to cover wrapper class defined in controller extension.But I am getting Error:

> Compile Error: Invalid type: testinvoice.wrapperItem at line 60 column
>   8

### Apex class:

```java
public without sharing class IITUpdateInvoice_EXT {
    public List<wrapperItem> milestoneList = new List<wrapperItem>();
    public list<Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c > updmilestone= new 
    List<Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c >();

    public IITUpdateInvoice_EXT(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    }

    Set<ID> mileId = new Set<Id>();
    ID studID = [Select Study_CELG_IIT__c from Payments_and_Invoicing_CELG_IIT__c where id=: Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get(IIT_Utility.Id_Param) limit 1].Study_CELG_IIT__c ;
    List<Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c > payList = [Select id,name,Payment_Amount_CELG_IPS__c from Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c where Study_CELG_IIT__c =: studID   limit 200];
    List<Payment_Milestone_Invoice_Association__c> junctionList = [Select id, Invoice_IMG__c,Payment_Milestone_IMG__c from Payment_Milestone_Invoice_Association__c where Invoice_IMG__c =:Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('if')]; 
    Public List<wrapperItem> getMilestoneObj(){

        for(Payment_Milestone_Invoice_Association__c junc: junctionList ){
            mileId.add(junc.Payment_Milestone_IMG__c);
        }
        for(Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c  payment : payList){
            if(!mileId.contains(payment.id))
                milestoneList.add(new wrapperItem(payment ,false));
        }
        return Milestonelist;
    }


    /* Wrapper Class to Display all Payment Milestones records with selected checkbox */
    public class wrapperItem{

        public Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c  milObj{get;set;}
        public Boolean selectBox{get;set;}

        @TestVisible public wrapperItem(Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c  milRec,Boolean checkBox){
            milObj = milRec;
            selectBox= checkBox; 
        }

    }

    /* Associate selected Payment milestones record to the Invoices */
    public void saveRec(){

        List<Payment_Milestone_Invoice_Association__c > juncList = new List<Payment_Milestone_Invoice_Association__c>();
        for(wrapperItem wrap:Milestonelist){

            if(wrap.selectBox == true){

                Payment_Milestone_Invoice_Association__c junc = new Payment_Milestone_Invoice_Association__c();
                junc.Invoice_IMG__c=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get(IIT_Utility.Id_Param);
                junc.Payment_Milestone_IMG__c = wrap.milObj.id;
                juncList.add(junc);
                updmilestone.add(wrap.milObj);
            }
        }

        if(juncList.size()>0){
            try{
                database.insert( juncList,true);
            }catch(Exception e){
                system.debug('Exception'+e);

            } 
        }  
    }
}
```

### Test class:

```java
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)

private class IITUpdateInvoiceTest{

    static testMethod void testIITUpdateInvoice(){

        Id approvedRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.study_celg_ips__C.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Approved IIT Study').getRecordTypeId();
        Id pubProfileId = [select id from profile where name ='Superuser_CELG_IPS_Pub'].id;
        Id personAccountRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Health Care Professional').getRecordTypeId();
        user usr = [select id from user where profileId=:pubProfileId and isActive=true limit 1];

        system.RunAs(usr){
            study_celg_ips__c oldStd= new study_celg_ips__C();
            insert oldStd;
        }

        product2 prod = new product2(name ='test',Approved_for_IITs__c=true,IsActive=true);

        insert prod;

        ID productId = [select id from product2 where id=:prod.id].id;

        Journal_Congress_CELG_IPS__c journal = new Journal_Congress_CELG_IPS__c(name='test');

        insert journal;

        ID journalID = [select id from Journal_Congress_CELG_IPS__c where id=:journal.id].id;


        study_celg_ips__c std = new study_celg_ips__C(recordtypeid= approvedRecordTypeId,Target_journal_CELG_IIT__c=journalID,                         Will_support_be_requested_CELG_IPS__c='No',Outcome_CELG_IPS__c='Ready for IRC',Outcome_Full_Concept_CELG_IIT__c='Approved' );

        insert std;

        ID studId = [select id from study_celg_ips__c where id=:std.id].id;

        Payments_and_Invoicing_CELG_IIT__c invoice = new Payments_and_Invoicing_CELG_IIT__c(Invoice_Number_CELG_IIT__c='123',Study_CELG_IIT__c=studId,Invoice_Amount_CELG_IIT__c=100);

        insert invoice;

        ID invoiceId = [select id from Payments_and_Invoicing_CELG_IIT__c where id=:invoice.id].id;

        Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c paymentMilestone = new Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c(Name ='test',Study_CELG_IIT__c=studId);

        insert paymentMilestone;

        ID paymentMilestoneId = [select id from Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c where id=:paymentMilestone.id].id;

        Payment_Milestone_Invoice_Association__c association = new Payment_Milestone_Invoice_Association__c(Invoice_IMG__c=invoiceId ,Payment_Milestone_IMG__c=paymentMilestoneId );

        insert association ;


        PageReference pageRef = Page.IIT_Update_Invoice;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id', invoiceId );
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        IITUpdateInvoice_EXT testinvoice = new IITUpdateInvoice_EXT(new ApexPages.StandardController(invoice));
        Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c  mile = new Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c();
        Boolean check = true;
        testinvoice.wrapperItem wrap = new testinvoice.wrapperItem(mile,check);

        testinvoice.saveRec();
        testinvoice.getMilestoneObj();

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Question 1:

Your creating child class with parent class instance.trying doing this, Create child class instance with parent class Name.

> Syntax:  OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = new OuterClass.InnerClass();

```
  IITUpdateInvoice_EXT.wrapperItem wrap = new IITUpdateInvoice_EXT.wrapperItem(mile,check);
```

> Question 2 :

In test Class call First

```
  testinvoice.getMilestoneObj();
```

Followed By

```
  testinvoice.saveRec();
```

because your **Milestonelist** generated by `testinvoice.getMilestoneObj()` and used in `testinvoice.saveRec();`

Finally code will look like this

```
    IITUpdateInvoice_EXT testinvoice = new IITUpdateInvoice_EXT(new ApexPages.StandardController(invoice));
    Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c  mile = new Payment_Schedule_CELG_IIT__c();
    Boolean check = true;
    IITUpdateInvoice_EXT.wrapperItem wrap = new IITUpdateInvoice_EXT.wrapperItem(mile,check);
    testinvoice.getMilestoneObj(); 
    testinvoice.saveRec();
```

> Question 3:

Reason behind your not able to pass the **if statement** because your setting **false** to **selectBox** in **wrapperItem** in the below statement and adding same **wrapperItem** to **milestoneList**.

```
   milestoneList.add(new wrapperItem(payment ,false));
```

And same **milestoneList** your checking for **selectBox** for **true**. either change the statement to

```
   milestoneList.add(new wrapperItem(payment ,true));
```

**OR**

**If your can't change original class code** 
then you have update the **wrapperItem** of **Milestonelist** after calling `testinvoice.getMilestoneObj();`

something like this,

```
  testinvoice.getMilestoneObj(); 
  public List<wrapperItem> TempMilestoneList = new List<wrapperItem>();
  For(wrapperItem item:testinvoice.milestoneList ) {
       wrapperItem TempItem=item;     //Avoid modify original object inside iteration , it **throw run time error**. So i create new **TempItem** and **TempMilestoneList** 
     TempItem.selectBox=true;
     TempMilestoneList.add(TempItem);    
    }
  testinvoice.milestoneList=TempMilestoneList;
  testinvoice.saveRec();
```

> [Best-practice-for-test-classes [Reference]](http://amitsalesforce.blogspot.in/2015/06/best-practice-for-test-classes-sample.html)

Comment: Okay @NITHESH,it is covering wrapper class.But I have one more question.I am using  `testinvoice.saveRec();` in test class, but it is not covering the line` for(wrapperItem wrap:Milestonelist){`  in apex class.

can you tell me is there anything else that I am missing

Comment: @devsfdc I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @NITHESH, `for(wrapperItem wrap:Milestonelist){` is getting with your code,but after that code is comapring checkbox field to TRUE 
 `if(wrap.selectBox == true){` .How can I replicate this checkbox update in test class.

Comment: @devsfdc I have updated the answer

Comment: Your Welcome...